# CSS Grid - Auto columns with auto width

Tags: css, css-grid

Im trying to have a grid auto wrap by using auto-fill, the problem is i want the width of the column ot be the max width of the content

Im trying this but it doesnt work:

```
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,min-content);
```

Is there any way to have the column set to the content size whilst also having the autofit propery?

Comment: no, this is not possible with CSS grid. it's a flexbox job

Comment: Yeah i thought the same... Shame = Il have to use percentages to dictate the number of columns instead of template-columns. Cheers

Comment: just something else to try (not test, just thinking out loud) what about  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(min-content, 1fr));

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the fit-content() function:

```
.container{
    display: grid;  
    grid-template-columns: auto fit-content(800px) auto;
}
```

The fit-content() CSS function clamps a given size to an available size according to the formula min(maximum size, max(minimum size, argument)).

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content